# ORA-00604 & ORA-08177 with entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, oracle12c

i'm beginner in asp.net mvc and entity framework. and i have started following this example in github : https://github.com/abdelkafiahmed/BankManagementSystem

i have created a new project MVC5 in visual studio 2012 ultimate, all model class (Banque, Client,...etc), and entity framework context class **BankDbContext**.

i have **oracle database 12c** version

Since there is not a connection string in **web.config** on this example, i decided to use entity framework for accessing to oracle database. i downloaded by **nuget** and installed the **oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework**, **oracle.ManagedDataAccess** and **EntityFramework v6** packages and t alrered the connection string given by thes packages to

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="ORCL" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl) 
    )
  )" />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BankDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=bcdratest;Password=bcdratest;Data Source=ORCL" />
</connectionStrings>
```

after i have created the Initializer class:

```
namespace BankAccountsManagementSystem.DataAccessLayer
{
    public class Initializer :DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BankDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(BankDbContext context)
        {


            using(var ctx = new BankDbContext())
            {
               var  banque = new Banque
               {
                   Nom="ENIT Bank",
                   ArgentDepose = 0.0m,
                   Capital =0.0m,
                   NbreClients = 0,
                   NbreComptes=0,
                   NbreCredits=0,
                   SommeCredits = 0
                };

                ctx.Banques.Add(banque);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
              }             
            }


        }
    }
```

i have started by creating a **BanquesController** and **Banques/Index** view when i executed the application, the database is created in first time. after, i created  **PersonneMoralesController** by scaffolding and altered the **index Action** by the code on this example

[here](https://github.com/abdelkafiahmed/BankManagementSystem/blob/master/BankAccountsManagementSystem/Controllers/PersonneMoralesController.cs)

but when executing the application i get an exception:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level string 1

ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
```

and database is not recreated.

i thought that i have got these errors because of the codes in **initializer** and **banque Controller Index Action**, two transactions in same Banques table, so i excluded this Initializer Class File.

but even this, the problem persists when the exectioning of application

why and how to fix this?

Comment: show your queries in controller, your entity classes

Comment: all i have done is in [here](https://github.com/abdelkafiahmed/BankManagementSystem/blob/master/BankAccountsManagementSystem/Controllers/BanquesController.cs) and in [here](https://github.com/abdelkafiahmed/BankManagementSystem/blob/master/BankAccountsManagementSystem/Controllers/PersonneMoralesController.cs). my entities classes are in [here](https://github.com/abdelkafiahmed/BankManagementSystem/tree/master/BankAccountsManagementSystem/Models)

Comment: Did you clean and/or the database, or did you just run the new code on old database from previous run? (edit: ah, I just noticed DropCreateDatabaseAlways, so that makes one answer, assuming it was invoked at all) Where does those exception come from? What were the stacktraces? Did you try inspecting the PL/SQL that was executed when these exception were thrown? That's for starters. If you don't know, then start with finding out the answers for these questions.

Comment: Also, next time please try to include important bits in English. Most of the people actually don't understand French. I know that Oracle.MDA translates error messages to your local language, but then.. it's not that hard to find out english versions.

Comment: i'm sorry excuse me

Comment: how i know all these? stacktraces, inspecting the PL/SQL that was executed when these exception were thrown, i started off cours with finding  out the answers for these questions, i find that isolation level have to be read-commited and not serialisable . but i didn't  anderstand why in this code source. and how to fix this with entity framework so i posted this message

Comment: what is the relationship with BanqueController and PersonneMoralController and isolation level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolved that issue by:
verify your DataSource in Web.Config. it contain the alias and description of TNS that it should be the same in tnsname.ora of your ODP.NET Installed in my machine.

verify if Oracle.ManagedDataAccess(.EntityFramework) package version is compatible with ODP.Net in my machine. my ODP.NET version is 12.1.024. so, the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess(.EntityFramework)  package have to be 12.1.024. and less than 12.2.0

i hope that help you.

Comment: hey bro. I have no idea where are this files. can u help me? Can u tell me where should i find this tnsname.ora? And where is the odp.net?